# Insserv rejected the script header

Tags: linux, debian, bash, shell, init.d

I was trying to make an init script for my debian install for supervisor.

```
insserv: Service \$remote_fs has to be enabled to start service supervisor                              
insserv: Service \$syslog has to be enabled to start service supervisor                                 
insserv: exiting now!                                                                                   
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
```

The full contents of the init script is here:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          supervisor
# Required-Start:    \$remote_fs \$syslog
# Required-Stop:     \$remote_fs \$syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Supervisor
# Description:       Supervisor service
### END INIT INFO

#
# Please remove the "Author" lines above and replace them
# with your own name if you copy and modify this script.

# Do NOT "set -e"

# PATH should only include /usr/* if it runs after the mountnfs.sh script
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="Supervisor Service"
NAME=supervisord
DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/\$NAME
DAEMON_ARGS="-c /etc/supervisord.conf"
PIDFILE=/var/run/\$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/\$NAME

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "\$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/\$NAME ] && . /etc/default/\$NAME

# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
. /lib/init/vars.sh

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.2-14) to ensure that this file is present
# and status_of_proc is working.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

#
# Function that starts the daemon/service
#
do_start()
{
        # Return
        #   0 if daemon has been started
        #   1 if daemon was already running
        #   2 if daemon could not be started
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile \$PIDFILE --exec \$DAEMON --test > /dev/null \
                || return 1
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile \$PIDFILE --exec \$DAEMON -- \
                \$DAEMON_ARGS \
                || return 2
        # Add code here, if necessary, that waits for the process to be ready
        # to handle requests from services started subsequently which depend
        # on this one.  As a last resort, sleep for some time.
}

#
# Function that stops the daemon/service
#
do_stop()
{
        # Return
        #   0 if daemon has been stopped
        #   1 if daemon was already stopped
        #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
        #   other if a failure occurred
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --pidfile \$PIDFILE --name \$NAME
        RETVAL="\$?"
        [ "\$RETVAL" = 2 ] && return 2
        # Wait for children to finish too if this is a daemon that forks
        # and if the daemon is only ever run from this initscript.
        # If the above conditions are not satisfied then add some other code
        # that waits for the process to drop all resources that could be
        # needed by services started subsequently.  A last resort is to
        # sleep for some time.
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry=0/30/KILL/5 --exec \$DAEMON
        [ "\$?" = 2 ] && return 2
        # Many daemons don't delete their pidfiles when they exit.
        rm -f \$PIDFILE
        return "\$RETVAL"
}

#
# Function that sends a SIGHUP to the daemon/service
#
do_reload() {
        #
        # If the daemon can reload its configuration without
        # restarting (for example, when it is sent a SIGHUP),
        # then implement that here.
        #
        start-stop-daemon --stop --signal 1 --quiet --pidfile \$PIDFILE --name \$NAME
        return 0
}

case "\$1" in
  start)
        [ "\$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting \$DESC" "\$NAME"
        do_start
        case "\$?" in
                0|1) [ "\$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
                2) [ "\$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac
        ;;
  stop)
        [ "\$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping \$DESC" "\$NAME"
        do_stop
        case "\$?" in
                0|1) [ "\$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
                2) [ "\$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac
        ;;
  status)
        status_of_proc "\$DAEMON" "\$NAME" && exit 0 || exit \$?
        ;;
  #reload|force-reload)
        #
        # If do_reload() is not implemented then leave this commented out
        # and leave 'force-reload' as an alias for 'restart'.
        #
        #log_daemon_msg "Reloading \$DESC" "\$NAME"
        #do_reload
        #log_end_msg \$?
        #;;
  restart|force-reload)
        #
        # If the "reload" option is implemented then remove the
        # 'force-reload' alias
        #
        log_daemon_msg "Restarting \$DESC" "\$NAME"
        do_stop
        case "\$?" in
          0|1)
                do_start
                case "\$?" in
                        0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
                        1) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Old process is still running
                        *) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Failed to start
                esac
                ;;
          *)
                # Failed to stop
                log_end_msg 1
                ;;
        esac
        ;;
  *)
        #echo "Usage: \$SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload}" >&2
        echo "Usage: \$SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart|force-reload}" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac
:
```

Can anyone please tell me where this error is coming from? I've not seen this kind of error before.

This is how I use this script:

```
ln -s $HOME/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
ln -s $HOME/init/supervisor /etc/init.d/supervisor
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/supervisor
update-rc.d supervisor defaults
```

Comment: Could you tell us how exactly you call `insserv`? Your script header works for me.

Comment: I have updated my question to include how I use this script. I don't directly call insserv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your `$` are escaped: `\$`.

Don't do that, youneed the variables, not the litteral dollar signs... ;)

Comment: Ah good spot. I'm new to this, do I want to be finding and replacing every instance of \$ and replace with $

Comment: @Jimmy yes you do, otherwise the LSB header (the Required-* lines especially) is not parse-able by `insserv`. But also the other occurrences are "wrong".